# Where's this tarn in Mt Garibaldi?

Tags: identify-this, british-columbia

1. Picture is from [5:10](https://youtu.be/KLbCRZ06KD8?t=310). I can't remember when in the video, but one of the ladies said this was taken at Mt Garibaldi.
2. Can I drive up to this [tarn](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tarn)? If not, can it be accessed effortlessly?

[image]

Comment: A horror lives about this tarn, and cleaves like its own mists to all the mountain side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The peaks in the background look like [The Black Tusk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Tusk).  Since the higher of its two peaks is to the south, and appears on the left in this photo, it must have been taken somewhere to the east, and seems to be at or near the treeline.  So I would guess that the tarn in the photo may be [Helm Lake](https://caltopo.com/m/PL8B) or another of the tarns near there.

You cannot drive there.  The nearest trailhead appears to be [Cheakamus Lake Road](https://goo.gl/maps/8N2NYV6ijd51QUNt7) , from which it is a hike of about 11 km, with about 950 m of elevation gain. [Rubble Creek](https://goo.gl/maps/YD7WCNfU4ZCPRks38) is a similar distance and about 1150 m of gain. Not terrible for a fit hiker, but certainly not "effortless".

Comment: Here are two more pics corroborating the location "Helm Lake": https://mapio.net/pic/p-25880923/ - and https://mapio.net/pic/p-122371746/